# Convert RSA Public key (1024 bit) format to DER ASN.1 public key for Java

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, asn.1, jce

Here is my Code for generating RSA key

```
public static void generateRsaKeyPair() {
  try {
      KeyPairGenerator keyPairGene = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
      keyPairGene.initialize(512);
      KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGene.genKeyPair();
      serverPublicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
      serverPrivateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } finally{
  }
 }
```

Now I want to convert DER/ASN.1 Encoded bytes, Also know what are the default encoded format use when generating RSA key using Java JCE API.

Answer (score 2):

The RSA key pair that is created using the `SunRsaSign` provider consists of an internal representation mainly consisting of `BigInteger` values. RSA is an algorithm that is using integer algorithmic after all. Internally it is not likely to be encoded in ASN.1 as the algorithm cannot be performed using binary. You can use your debugger to browse through the internal fields, but note that the internal structure is *an implementation detail* and should not be relied upon.

To convert the public key to ASN.1 you just need to call `serverPublicKey.getEncoded()` and you'll get a SubjectPublicKeyInfo structure, which is an ASN.1 data structure defined for X.509 certificates, encoded using binary BER encoding scheme (DER is a subset of BER, usually the encoding is DER compatible). It consists of a sequence that contains an OID - indicating the RSA key type - and the PKCS#1 encoded public key. You can find the details in [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3279#section-2.3), [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3279#section-2.3.1) and of course structure RSAPublicKey in [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#appendix-C).

You can also call `serverPrivateKey.getEncoded()` to get an unprotected, inner PKCS#8 structure. However, it is highly questionable if you should do that. You should not distribute unprotected private keys. If you need to store it, use a well protected PKCS#12 key store instead.

Comment: Hi Maarten Bodewes
By using serverPublickey.getEncoded(), I am getting encoded bytes which are in BER format as you said. But when we use this bytes we got invalid encoding error.
we are using third party Thales HSM commands and into that we need to pass DER ASN.1 encoded bytes.
so, any other way to converting encoded BER encoding scheme to DER encoding.
also suggest me any API which can converting to DER ASN.1 encoding,if have.

Comment: ASN.1 is a language to describe the structure of the key, DER is a way to encode the key. What is missing in the question is what kind of format your key needs to be in. But more importantly if you have an HSM and you then generate a key pair in software then you may not get the point of using a HSM in the first place.

Comment: To be more succinct: ASN.1 can be used to describe a format. BER can be used to encode the format. What's missing is the format.

Comment: I've now voted to close this question as your information about the public key format is still pending.